# PayPal Incoming JSON request does not map to API reques

Tags: json, laravel, paypal

**Hi guys This is my first integration in PayPal and I am a little confused, so i have had a problem for days When I try to call the PayPal API its gives me this error "Incoming JSON request does not map to API reques" with this Error type MALFORMED_REQUEST Please need help**

```
  public function payment(Request $request)
        {
              $config = [
                "id"  => "AYfR2ytBTo3K31b0hV7lIC3ioXz6cTuZusjKQE5XUVtyZ8E1FXikRuNQBVZfKpnqCE7Q-Jjza2y1F24c",
                "secrete" => "EJFiXlkNOhlt3uokThwW8VOAe4S7DE_GaeEuEXZcx2hWYYx1RbNHSINVLpBok3QIft8Csf1V8vk2tt2_"
            ];
            $apiContext = new ApiContext(
                new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
                    $config['id'],
                    $config['secrete']
                )
            );
            $payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
            $payment->setIntent('sale');
            $redirectUrls = (new  \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls()) 
            ->setReturnUrl('http://localhost/samakeurback/public/success.php')
            ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost/samakeurback/public/');
            $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
            
    //      On definie le payeur
            $payment->setPayer((new \PayPal\Api\Payer())
                ->setPaymentMethod('paypal'));
                $projet = Projet::find(2);
                $list = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();
                $item_payment =  array();
                $item = (new \PayPal\Api\Item())
                ->setName($projet->name)
                ->setPrice(10000)
                ->setQuantity(1)
                ->setCurrency('EUR')
                ;
                
                $list->addItem($item);
                $details =  (new \PayPal\Api\Details())
                      ->setSubTotal(10000);
                      
                $amount = (new \PayPal\Api\Amount())
                  ->setTotal(10000)
                  ->setCurrency("EUR")
                  ->setDetails($details);
                
                  $transactions = (new \PayPal\Api\Transaction())
                      ->setItemList($list)
                      ->setDescription("Payment des frais pour le projet")
                      ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid())
                      ->setAmount($amount)
                      ->setCustom($projet->id);
                    //    dd($transactions);
                      $payment->setTransactions($transactions);

                      try{
                        $payment->create($apiContext);
                        header('Location:'. $payment->getApprovalLink());
                      }
                      catch(\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e)
                      {
                          var_dump(json_decode($e->getData()));
                      }
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the deprecated v1 PayPal-PHP-SDK?

You may have better luck with the current v2 [Checkout-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK)